# row and match function for table in 2 different excel files

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, row

I have recently become responsible for some important excel files at work.
The first thing I want to do is facilitate them with some excel functions to avoid possible errors.

I have already been able to add some of them, but I am now bumping into one and can't figure it out.
I have a table with name, first name and date of birth (and more info) in excel 1.

In excel 2, I want my function to look up the date of birth in excel 1 using the first name and surname.
So if the name and first name in excel 2 matches the one in excel 1 then give me the date of birth that matches this name and first name.

I tried using the index function, row and column function for this, but it just doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone guide me on this?

Thanks in advance

=INDEX(A21:I34;;COLUMN(E21))
i thought of using the row function and than looking for a match with name en first name. But something isn't working with that function.

Comment: You may try `FILTER()` function. Share few sample data and show desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Excel are integer numbers, so because of this you may use functions designed to return a numeric value, like SUMIFS. This function will sum *birthdate* based on criterias (*name* and *first name*)

Just as example:

[image]

```
=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$7;$A$4:$A$7;G4;$B$4:$B$7;H4)
```

Notice in yellow *Black Widow* returns `00/01/1900`. That means this character **is not** on Excel 1. Actually SUMIFS returns 0 on this case because there is no match at all. You can combine this with an IF to get an appropiate output. Something like

[image]

```
=IF(SUMIFS($C$4:$C$7;$A$4:$A$7;G4;$B$4:$B$7;H4)=0;"Not found";SUMIFS($C$4:$C$7;$A$4:$A$7;G4;$B$4:$B$7;H4))
```

[SUMIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) works great to locate numeric values. Actually sometimes I use it instead of VLOOKUP to locate numeric values based on multiple criteria.

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, one of which is discussed [here](https://exceljet.net/formulas/xlookup-with-multiple-criteria) but I'll explain the way I learned to do this:

Basically you combine the two cells you're going with (can use a delimiter in between if you'd like) and then do the same with the look up columns. The only caveat is that you need them to be the same length and it can't be the whole column, i.e. `A:A&B:B` won't work but `$A$1:$A$10&$B$1:$B$9` won't either, `$A$1:$A$10&$B$1:$B10` will.

Some things may vary for you due to language/location settings like ";" -> ","

For a normal range:
[image]

```
=XLOOKUP(A2&B2;[Book1]Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10&[Book1]Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10;[Book1]Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10;"NOT FOUND")
```

and for looking it up in a table, it'll look something like this:
[image]

```
=XLOOKUP(A5&B5;Book1!Table1[Name]&Book1!Table1[Sir Name];Book1!Table1[Birth date];"NOT FOUND")
```

Hope this explains it for you.